# Optimizing sub-queries and joins

Tags: sql, sql-optimization

I have 2 tables that can have many-to-many relations between them:

```
Person (pid, name, a,b) , 
Attributes (attribId, d,e)
```

The mapping is present in a separate table:

```
Mapping (mapId, pid, attribId)
```

The goal is to get all Person and Attributes values for a person who qualifies the filter criteria. The filter criteria is based on a column in the Attributes table. Eg - column d.

For example:

```
Person ->
(1,'person1','a1','b1')
(2,'person2','a1','b1')

Attributes ->
(1,'d1','e1')
(2,'d2','e1')
(3,'d3','e1')
(4,'d3','e2')

Mapping ->
(1,1,1)
(2,1,2)
(3,1,3)

After running the query ->
Result:
(1,'person1','a1','b1')(1,'d1','e1')
(1,'person1','a1','b1')(2,'d2','e1')
(1,'person1','a1','b1')(3,'d3','e1')
```

Query that i have been trying ->

```
select p.*, a.*
from
    Person p 
left outer join
    Mapping m 
        on p.pid=m.pid 
left outer join
    Attributes a 
        on m.attribId=a.attribId 
where
    p.pid in (select p1.pid
from
    Person p1 
left outer join
    Mapping m1 
        on p1.pid=m1.pid 
left outer join
    Attributes a1
        on m1.attribId=a1.attribId 
where
    a1.d = 'd1')
```

Similarly, I also have to discard Person entries that have a certain d value.

So, currently, the final query looks like this:

```
SELECT
  p.*,
  a.*
FROM Person p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Mapping m
  ON p.pid = m.pid
LEFT OUTER JOIN Attributes a
  ON m.attribId = a.attribId
WHERE p.pid IN (SELECT
  p1.pid
FROM Person p1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Mapping m1
  ON p1.pid = m1.pid
LEFT OUTER JOIN Attributes a1
  ON m1.attribId = a1.attribId
WHERE a1.d = 'd1')
AND p.pid NOT IN (SELECT
  p2.pid
FROM Person p2
LEFT OUTER JOIN Mapping m2
  ON p2.pid = m2.pid
LEFT OUTER JOIN Attributes a2
  ON m2.attribId = a2.attribId
WHERE a2.d = 'd5');
```

It feels like this query is inefficient since the same join is done at 3 places. Is there a way to reuse the join for all the sub-queries and make this more efficient?

[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e8167/4)

Comment: Please format your final query and add http://sqlfiddle.com demo with desired result.

Comment: Thanks @lad2025, added the demo and formatted the final query.

Comment: What kind of DB is it?

Comment: They are oracle databases. But the version changes based on the domain it's run in, and it's run in multiple domains. As far as i know, most of them are 11g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all persons satisfying the filter using:

```
select m.pid
from mapping m join
     attributes a
     on m.attribId = a.attribId and a.d = 'dS';
```

You can get all person/attribute combinations using `IN` or `EXISTS` or a `JOIN`.  Which is better depends on the database.  But the idea is:

```
select p.*, a.*
from person p join
     mapping m
     on p.pid = m.pid join
     attributes a
     on m.attribId = a.attribId
where p.pid in (select m.pid
                from mapping m join
                     attributes a
                     on m.attribId = a.attribId and a.d = 'dS'
               );
```

I see no reason to have `left join`s for these queries.

EDIT:

If the filter criteria is based on multiple columns, then use `group by` and `having` for the subquery:

```
select m.pid
from mapping m join
     attributes a
     on m.attribId = a.attribId and a.d = 'dS'
group by m.pid
having sum(case when a.d = 'dS' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and -- at least one of these
       sum(case when a.d = 'd1' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;    -- none of these
```

Comment: I am still going through this. Will try your suggestions and respond soon. Thanks Gordon!

Answer (score 1):

First thing I have noticed is that you use left join in subqueries, inner join would work as well and is much faster. Second remove Person from nested selects because it is not needed.

```
select m2.pid
from
Mapping m2
inner join
    Attributes a2 
        on m2.attribId=a2.attribId 
where
a2.d = 'd5'
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll get rid of the unnecessary join with the Person table in the sub-queries. The inner join would work for the 'WHERE p.pid IN' scenario since a person who does not have a Mapping should be discarded in this case. But for the 'WHERE p.pid NOT IN ' case, a person who does not have a Mapping is still valid. So I guess I'll have to user the left outer join just for that one.

Comment: I'm wrong, inner join can be used for both the sub-queries. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We could also do something like this

```
select p.* from person where pid in 
(Select m.pid from mapping m where m.aid in
(select aid from attribute a where a.d = "something"))
```

I know there is this discussion of joins vs sub-queries but in this case, I think sub-queries will be faster.